# How to echo a mysqli_query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to echo a phone number from my database using php but it keeps returning blank. I've been fiddling around with it all night and looking at various examples but I've not been able to get it to work. Can someone help me please?

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$sql = 'SELECT phone FROM users WHERE ID = 29' ;
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($results);
    echo $row['phone'];
```

Comment: You probably need to access the array-elements differently, but the issue is that you've got one too much identifier in your fetch-method. `mysqli_fetch_row($$results)` find one mistake :-) (You're not using variable variables)

Comment: Extra dollar sign on results? Edit: ninja'd!

Comment: Seems like you want to fetch associative instead, `mysqli_fetch_row()` => `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: why dont use mysqli_error : mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); which will help you debug your query

Comment: Use  echo $row[0];

Comment: Troubleshooting 101: "Ive been unable to get it to work" is useless.  Why doesn't it work? Are there any errors or warnings? (Be sure error reporting is turned on!).  Further, learn how to use `var_dump()` to troubleshoot - for example, right after `$row = mysql_fetch_row( $results );` - if you add `var_dump( $row );`, what do you get?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

Since your using **mysqli_fetch_row** it returns result enumerated array which means it returns the result row array staring from 0 offset.

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

ie.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($results);
//Now $row columns can be accessed by $row[0] $row[1] and so on.
```

On the other hand if you use **mysqli_fetch_assoc** then the result will be returned as associative array ie key value pairs

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

ie.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
//Now you can use $row as $row['phone'], $row['id'] and so on
```